# What to use in python3.x to fetch non-ascii values from console

Tags: c, python-3.x, input

I am trying to form a pipe, where a program written in C gives its continuous output with `write()`. This stream of data shall be accepted by python script and processed further.
By using `input()` (python 3.x) I was able to catch the data when C-written source program was giving its data out with `printf()`, anyway to speed up I changed to `write()` to console.

And this is where the problem start: From now on I am unable to fetch the data with python script, because `input()` doesn't want to accept non-ascii values. I know, `write()` gives a binary data instead of strings.

1. Is there any other way for python to accept the data from outside, preferably from console, where data consists non-ascii values (preferably binary input)?

I have tried to modify the C program to form a ascii string. The array of chars plus terminating zero (also: zero-terminated string, with CR and LF+CR), anyway python seems to read further behind terminating zero and then giving `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 130: invalid continuation byte` error, where sent string was 4 characters long (C - array: [99, 0, 10, 13] which is equivalent to 'c' zero-terminated and LF and CR).

So - trying to implement other solution - question 2. Is there a possibility to limit the length of `input()` before python grabs unknown portion of data from console and throws errors?

Comment: In what way do you expect `write` to "speed things up"?  There is minimal additional overhead in the function calls to printf, and the buffering layer in printf is almost certainly implemented more correctly that any buffering you are doing (if you are even attempting to match your writes to optimize the throughput).  If you are not optimizing your writes carefully, you are almost certainly slowing things down.

Comment: Are you writing the terminating nulls when you use `write` instead of `printf`?  Why?  That changes the behavior.

Comment: It is certainly incorrect to output a NUL byte in the middle of your output, as in `[99,0,10,13]`. But the `\n\r` is also incorrect. (`\n` is almost certainly sufficient, and if for some reason you feel compelled to send `\r` as well, it has to come *before* the `\n`.) In any event, there is no `0xe9` in that line, which suggests that you are writing different data than you think you are (or, at least, different data then your question implies you are writing). A [mre] would be helpful, as always.

Answer (score 1):

For reading binary, you should probably use the `.read()` method on a file object. And the object you want to use is probably `sys.stdin.buffer`.

Check [the docs for the `io` module](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and for [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the documentation for [sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) would be helpful here. In particular there is a very helpful note contained in the documentation:

> Note: To write or read binary data from/to the standard streams, use the underlying binary buffer object. For example, to write bytes to stdout, use sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc').

For you second question, the default [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function reads in lines at a time.